# Conditional Redirect by Day of the Week

Tags: javascript, redirect, shopify

I'm looking for a way to redirect one page to another based on the day of the week. I only want the page in question to redirect from 12:00am EST Sunday until 2:00pm EST Tuesday.

Here's what I have. When I tested it, it did not redirect to the new URL.

```
<script> 
const rules = [ 
{ day: 0, url: 'https://www.whitehorsewine.com/pages/our-kitchen-1' }, // Redirect for Sunday
{ day: 1, url: 'https://www.whitehorsewine.com/pages/our-kitchen-1' }, // Redirect for Monday
{ day: 2, from: 0, to: 11, url: 'https://www.whitehorsewine.com/pages/our-kitchen-1' }, // Redirect for Tuesday until 2pm 
]; 
function getRedirectUrl() { 
const now = new Date(); 
const today = now.getDay(); 
const hours = now.getHours(); 
const first = rules.find(item => 
(item.day === undefined || item.day === today) && 
((item.from === undefined || item.from >= hours) && (item.to === undefined || item.to < hours)) 
); 
return first.url; 
} 
function redirect() { 
window.location.href = getRedirectUrl(); 
} 

</script>
```

Not sure if it matters, but I'm working within the theme editor on Shopify.

Comment: What is it doing right now? How is that different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: I visited the page on Monday and it did not redirect to the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close!

Your comparison operators are just backwards.

So the way you are structured and the data shown it is impossible to find a time that is both less than `0` and greater than `11`.

So just change

`item.from >= hours` to `item.from <= hours`

`item.to === undefined || item.to < hours` to `item.to === undefined || item.to > hours`

I would also add some guard statements to your return and redirect logic. Also make sure that you are calling `redirect()` somewhere. I don't see it in your sample and that would also be another reason for it not to run.

```
const rules = [ 
  { day: 0, url: 'https://www.whitehorsewine.com/pages/our-kitchen-1' }, // Redirect for Sunday
  { day: 1, url: 'https://www.whitehorsewine.com/pages/our-kitchen-1' }, // Redirect for Monday
  { day: 2, from: 0, to: 11, url: 'https://www.whitehorsewine.com/pages/our-kitchen-1' }, // Redirect for Tuesday until 2pm 
]; 

function getRedirectUrl() { 
  const now = new Date(); 
  const today = now.getDay(); 
  const hours = now.getHours(); 
  const first = rules.find(item => 
    (item.day === undefined || item.day === today) && 
    ((item.from === undefined || item.from <= hours) && (item.to === undefined || item.to > hours)) 
); 
  if (first === undefined) { return undefined } // Guard to return undefined instead of erroring out if it can't find a matching rule
  return first.url; 
} 

function redirect() { 
  let url = getRedirectUrl()
  // Guard to catch the undefined and not call the redirect on an undefined resource.
  if ( url !== undefined ) { window.location.href = url }
} 

redirect() // Added the call to redirect so the code actually gets run.
```

Comment: Thank you! This was my first attempt at patching a script together and not just making minor edits an existing one, so I was in uncharted territory. Really appreciate the encouraging response!